# How to use previously defined methods (funcs) in "export" function in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, csv

Been updating a Python/Django project, and I know pretty much nothing about it, whatsoever.

Currently I have been trying to export a current view (change list) to CSV. The columns are printed fine, all the methods (functions) are displaying all info as they should/expected.

When hitting "Export" link the hardcore starts, and it's been up for weeks now.

Finally something started to show in my .csv file, yet still I cannot print out methods like `how_many` or `postal_code` inside the loop **`for elem in csv_elements:`**

Below is a partially printed class that takes care of displaying columns on the screen and then export them to the `.csv` file. I didn't include all of it, just parts I personally think are important to show (I may be very wrong about this of course). Basically everything down to `export_this_list` works just fine.

What syntax should I use to be able to re-use already defined functions (methods) inside the last function (method)?

```
class EnrolmentAdmin(TrainingAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """EnrolmentAdmin is used for registering Enrolment model."""

    form = EnrolmentForm
        .
          .
    list_display = ('date', 'training', 'postal_code', 'how_many')
        .
          .
    def postal_code(self, obj):
        return obj.invoice_data['postal_code']

    def how_many(self, obj):
        return obj.total_participants

    how_many.short_description = "How Many Persons"
        .
          .
    def export_this_list(self, request):
        """Generates participants list in Excel sheet."""
        filename = 'Orders.csv'
        csv_elements = Enrolment.objects.all()

        if not csv_elements:
            response = HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse('admin:xxxxxx_training_change', args=[object_id]))
            msg = _('There are no orders yet.')
            messages.error(request, msg)
        else:
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            response[
                'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(
                filename)
            #fieldnames = ['Date', 'Training', 'Postal code', 'How many']
            fieldnames = ['How many']

            sheet = csv.DictWriter(
                response, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
            sheet.writeheader()

            for elem in csv_elements:
                sheet.writerow({
                    'How many': self.how_many
                })

        return response
```

Comment: You should **call** the function like this: `self.how_many(obj)`

Comment: I tried to use just that, this error occured: "NameError: name 'obj' is not defined". So I added "obj" to the function arguments, having this as a result: "def export_this_list(self, request, obj):". After that this error occured: TypeError: export_this_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

Comment: Come on, you are in a loop where the item is called `elem` so you should do `self.how_many(elem)`. Jahongir was just giving you an example.

Comment: I cannot take a hint not knowing Django, epecially since `obj` is used as an argument in some functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **call** the function like this: `self.how_many(obj)`

In your case, it would be:

```
for elem in csv_elements:
    sheet.writerow({
        'How many': self.how_many(elem)
    })
```